# install composer-php plugin from zip file

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having some issues installing a plugin into my application from a .zip file using composer.

I have a private composer plugin in a `.zip` file. I downloaded it in my pc. I want to add this plugin into my application using composer. So that it unzip in vendor folder and work like others plugins. I am not sure is it possible or not?

I can add it manually into autoload psr-4 classmap.

Comment: The whole point of Composer is that it does this kind of thing _for you_. Why are you trying to add this library manually?

Comment: Why do you want it in composer? What composer should do with it?

Comment: I want because someone can install private package downloading zip file from my company site. I don't want to give my bitbucket link.

Comment: @Chris Another good reason for this is that the company publishing the file chooses to only provide is as a ZIP file via HTTP download.  It's these kind of opinionated aspects of Composer that make Composer such as PITA to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I install my private CakePHP plugin by manually editing composer.json and providing this configuration:

```
{
  "name": "cakephp/app",
  "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
  "homepage": "http://cakephp.org",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repositories": [{
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
          "type": "cakephp-plugin",
          "name": "company/my-private-lib",
          "version": "0.9.0",
          "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "folder-where-zip-is/name-of-zip-file-1.0.0.zip"
          },
          "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
              "MyPrivateLib\\": "src"
            }
          }
      }
  }],
...
}
```

Then I run `composer install company/my-private-lib`

I hope it helps you.

Comment: actually it should be `composer require company/my-private-lib`